# Deleting a record from the datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In VB2012, I have a created a student management software with SQL2012 as the back-end. The below code is used for deleting a selected record from the datagridview when DELETE button is clicked:

```
 Private Sub Delete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Delete.Click
        Dim DelStudent As StudentDataSet1._masterRow
        DelStudent= CType(CType(StudentmasterBindingSource.Current, DataRowView).Row, StudentDataSet1.Student_masterRow)
        DelStudent.Delete()
        Me.Validate()
        Me.StudentmasterBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.Student_masterTableAdapter.Update(StudentDataSet1.Student_master)
End Sub
```

But instead of the selected row being deleted, the first row gets deleted. Please help...

Comment: You can delete or update your database by just updating the dataset you have, but have you ever tried deleting against the database using SQL statements? I suggest you use SQL statements to query or execute against the database and rebind whatever you have onto the grid, it should be more prectical in the long run, especially if you have plans of using another scripting language other than VB.NET. SQL remains the same whatever back-end you use, pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

Selected row is not necessary current, from the perspective of binding source. You need to be using [DataGridView.SelectedRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Each is a [DataGridViewRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and you should be able to retrieve [DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), cast it to `DataRow`, and use `Delete` on that.

Answer (score 0):

the code below is also helpful

```
 Private Sub btnRemoveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemoveItem.Click
        If datagridviewname.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = datagridviewname.SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                datagridviewname.Rows.RemoveAt(datagridviewname.SelectedRows(i).Index)
            Next
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Select Row to remove")
        End If
    End Sub
```